# my HTML is not being prepended to my DOM

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

**Inside DataTable initComplete**

```
$('#' + key.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "-") + '-table').prepend("<div class='toolbar'>" + createButtonBar(year) + "<label id='categorySelection' style='padding-top: 5px;'>Select Category:</label><select style='margin-left:5px;margin-right: 10px;margin-left: 5px;' class='form-control input-sm' id='categorySelectBox'/>");
```

**function outside DataTable**

```
function createButtonBar(years) {
        var htmlString = "";

        years = years.reverse();

        htmlString += "<div id='#above1200buttonbar'>stuff</div>"
        years.forEach(function(entry) {
            htmlString += "<label><input name='date' type='radio' value='" + entry + "'>" + entry + "</label>";
        });
        $('#above1200buttonbar').replaceWith(htmlString);
        console.log(htmlString);
    }
```

**from console.log()**

```
<div id='#above1200buttonbar'><div class='hide-below-1200 btn-group' style='padding: 5px 0 5px 0;' data-toggle='buttons'><label class='btn btn-default btn-sm active year-btn'><input name='date' type='radio' id='mybuttons' value='all'>All</label><label class='btn btn-default btn-sm year-btn'><input name='date' type='radio' value='2016'>2016</label><label class='btn btn-default btn-sm year-btn'><input name='date' type='radio' value='2015'>2015</label>
```

The issue is that my built html is not being prepended to the DOM.

---

```
var cleanKey = $('#' + key.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "-") + '-table');
```

I did it to prevent making mistakes when copying and pasting or editing

Comment: you won't be able to, jQuery works with what's loaded on page load - anything new isn't in the dom, but you can use `$(document).find('#my-dynamic-element')` to get it in jQuery

Comment: $(document).find(cleanKey).prepend("<div class='toolbar'>" + createButtonBar(year) + "<label id='categorySelection' style='padding-top: 5px;'>Select Category:</label><select style='margin-left:5px;margin-right: 10px;margin-left: 5px;' class='form-control input-sm' id='categorySelectBox'/>"); 

This didnt work either @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs

Comment: where is cleanKey declared? not seeing it in your code?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs updating question to show the cleankey reference

Comment: hmm try `console.log($(document).find(cleanKey))` - see if returns an object - if not then it's not finding it properly (and if that's the case, try passing in the string as it would appear (so without the .toLowerCase etc))

Comment: Console.log indicated there was an object present

n.fn.init [table#other-education-materials-table.table.table-striped.dataTable.no-footer, prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: document]

Comment: Could you provide a JSBin/JSFiddle/CodePen demonstrating the issue?

Comment: I could do a JSFiddle but the CSS won't work because there are a ton of files that manage it

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bb7bz58p/1/ code on JSFiddle. CSS files not there yet but i am working on it. Where should I put the sample JSON file?

Comment: Please provide a full [mcve] in the question itself. Break the problem down until you have the minimum code that is possible and still shows your issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "#above1200buttonbar" ).append(htmlString);
```

Try that